# How to search for subroutines/modules within MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fortran, intel-fortran

Is there a way in MS Visual Studio 2010 (I use Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011) to search for subroutines and modules? For example if I am in a subroutine (written by somebody else) that calls another subroutine subname, I usually use "find in files" to find this latter subroutine, but is there a more direct way, e.g by right clicking on the function (or  module) name? i could not find any.
Thanks

Comment: You mean in MS Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I mean MS Visual Studio.I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

As of Composer XE 2011 update 6 (compiler version 12.1), the style of source browsing that you are after is available within the Intel Fortran Visual Studio integration.  You need to make sure that you have enabled it - under Tools > Options in the Text Editor > Fortran > Advanced category set Collect Call/Callers graph information and Collect Object Browser information to true and Disable Database to false.

A restart of Visual Studio may be required.  Modules and procedures in the current solution can then be browsed using the drop down lists at the top of the source code editing windows and various options on the right click menu in the editor window.

For solutions with large code bases, acquisition and maintenance of the of information that the source browser relies on can be rather resource hungry.  Support for procedures accessed via a generic interface is poor.

Comment: Ok I have the update 5, I dont have the advanced category. I will update it. A couple of questions:
1)Does it work also for solutions having both fortran and C++ projects? 
2?)there is also the option to click on a variable and see where it has been defined?
Thanks
A.

Comment: I doubt mixed projects are supported.  Locating (perhaps local only?) variable definitions is supported (also noting that the definition of a Fortran variable can be spread across multiple statements).  Specific questions are best directed to the [Intel forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Source Editor Enhancements by Fortran CodeNav.

   **Fortran CodeNav** is an useful extension for fortran coding with MS VS. It supports "Jump to declaration of member","List usages of element","Auto-complete" and search. I recommand Fortran CodeNav because it supports shortcut keys. Fortran CodeNav for VS2010 can be downloaded at its [old site](https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/FCN/Home).
2. Source Editor Enhancements by IVF

   @IanH's answer has mentioned about it. Maybe you could find the guide to Source Editor Enhancements in developer guide and reference book of your IVF version. As of XE2018 update 1(IVF Compiler 18.0), the guide is [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-18.0-developer-guide-and-reference-using-source-editor-enhancements-in-microsoft-visual-studio). But it doesn't support shortcut keys.